# Javascript function calling

Tags: javascript, object

I'm declaring an object "Members" in my app global variable:

```
var MyShulApp = MyShulApp || {}; 

MyShulApp.Members = (function () {

    function Members() {

    }

    Members.prototype.getMembersList = function () {

        var list = [{ name: "john", age: 90 }, { name: "kaly", age: 90 }, { name: "steve", age: 90}];

        return list;
    }

    return Members;
})
```

I want to be able to call getMembersList(), so i do this:

```
var lst = oMembers.getMembersList();
```

but it's not working and I get undefined.

This works:

```
var membersList = oMembers.prototype.getMembersList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT(picture added):**
[image]

Comment: How is `oMembers` defined?

Comment: you need call your anonymouse function

Comment: @Grundy: post that as the answer!

Comment: @maerics Oriol already post it :-) i'm so sloooow :-)

Comment: i added a picture showing the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `oMembers`.

But my guess is that you wanted to use a self-executing function:

```
var MyShulApp = MyShulApp || {}; 
MyShulApp.Members = (function () {
    function Members() {}
    Members.prototype.getMembersList = function () {
        var list = [{ name: "john", age: 90 }, { name: "kaly", age: 90 }, { name: "steve", age: 90}];
        return list;
    }
    return Members;
})();
```

Note I added the `()` at the end, to execute the function.

But you don't need that, you could just use

```
var MyShulApp = MyShulApp || {}; 
MyShulApp.Members = function Members() {};
MyShulApp.Members.prototype.getMembersList = function () {
    var list = [{ name: "john", age: 90 }, { name: "kaly", age: 90 }, { name: "steve", age: 90}];
    return list;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first create an instance of that object:

```
function Members() {
}

Members.prototype.getMembersList = function () {
    var list = [{ name: "john", age: 90 }, { name: "kaly", age: 90 }, { name: "steve", age: 90}];

    return list;
}

var oMembers = new Members('Male');
```

To read more about this head to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript